# How to implement pop function in a doubly linked python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

Below is the block of code i'm working on, it is for school so i'm not asking for the answer just some guidance. Been working on this for quite some time and maybe i'm just tried. Could someone explain to me the error of my ways?

```
def pop(self, idx=-1):
    """Deletes and returns the element at idx (which is the last element,
    by default)."""
    nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
    if nidx >= len(self):
        raise IndexError
    n = self.head
    for _ in range(self[-1]):
        n = n.next
    return n
    n.prior.next = n.next
    n.next.prior = n.prior
    self.length -= 1
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is your input? What is your output vs your expected output? Also you are aware none of the lines after the return will ever run right? The method exits at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your errors are all in these lines:

```
for _ in range(self[-1]):
    n = n.next
return n
```

The bounds you're using for your `range` call is bizarre. You probably want to iterate `nidx` times, not whatever `self[-1]` is.

You also probably don't want to `return` at that point, since a `return` stops the rest of the function from running. Try moving the `return` line to be below the unlinking code.

You'll also need to decide if you are supposed to be returning a node (which will have stray links if you don't reset `n.next` and `n.prior`) or a value contained within the node. Usually a linked list's nodes are implementation details that don't get exposed to outside code, so you'd return the value.